# Functionalities such as cash, split payments does not appear on square register app for transactions initiated by register api and Oauth flow

Tags: square-connect

When I initiate a transaction from my android app using the register API, it first goes through the oauth flow, then if the merchant allows the permissions(I used default permissions) it opens up the register app's transaction page (where merchant can charge a specific amount of money sent by my android app using credit card). But the merchant cannot see any other options other then credit card processing. How do I enable cash payment, Split Card payment methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tenderTypes.add(ChargeRequest.TenderType.CASH);`

Take a look at this page in the documentation:
https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/register/android/

And don't forget about the sample apps here: https://github.com/square/register-android-sdk

Comment: Unless you have disabled split tenders for your register account you should be able to split between any tenders you enabled with the `split` button in the top right.

Comment: I haven't disabled split option on my register account.
When I open the register app as a standalone app the split button shows up in the top right.
But, when I initiate a chargeRequest from my own android app (using register api) it opens up square register app, but the split button doesn't show up.

Comment: Are you using version 1.0? split tenders was released in version 1.1 (fairly recently) so you may need to upgrade.